# spoj program 2: prime generator. time exceeding

Tags: python

i am new to python and just now started solving spoj problems.
for the second ques i did this:

```
from math import sqrt; 
from itertools import count, islice

tn=int(input())
s=[]

for items in range(tn):
    s.append(input())


def prime(n1,n2): 
    while n1<=n2:
        if( n1 > 1 and all(n1%i for i in islice(count(2), int(sqrt(n1)-1)))):
            print(n1)
        n1+=1

for item in range(len(s)):

    l1=s[item].split(" ")
    n1=int(l1[0])
    n2=int(l1[1])
    prime(n1,n2)
```

its showing time limit exceeded. am i doing something stupid??

Comment: What are you trying to do in the top loop on range(tn)?  Are you asking the user for a sequence of values?

Comment: You are reading the list input wrong. Use sys.stdin for input. check this link http://discuss.spoj.com/t/how-to-input-numbers-in-python/7172

Comment: @joelgoldstick with tn i want to run the loop for given no. of test cases. so that if there are 3 test cases than 3 items should be inserted in list s.

Comment: @minocha thanks. it made many points clear.